# Try to fix 'object is not callable' problem

Tags: python, transformer-model, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I'm new to nn.lightning style, and I'm working on a space-time transformer project. I try to modify the training script to use my own data set for training (the original version is using CIFAR10/MNIST).

I've got a problem with the data module.

Here's the code.

```
def create_dset(config):
    INV_SCALER = lambda x: x
    SCALER = lambda x: x
    NULL_VAL = None
    PLOT_VAR_IDXS = None
    PLOT_VAR_NAMES = None
    PAD_VAL = None


    if config.dset in ["mnist", "cifar"]:
        if config.dset == "mnist":
            config.target_points = 28 - config.context_points
            datasetCls = stf.data.image_completion.MNISTDset
            PLOT_VAR_IDXS = [18, 24]
            PLOT_VAR_NAMES = ["18th row", "24th row"]
        else:
            config.target_points = 32 * 32 - config.context_points
            datasetCls = stf.data.image_completion.CIFARDset
            PLOT_VAR_IDXS = [0]
            PLOT_VAR_NAMES = ["Reds"]
        DATA_MODULE = stf.data.DataModule(
            datasetCls=datasetCls,
            dataset_kwargs={"context_points": config.context_points},
            batch_size=config.batch_size,
            workers=config.workers,
            overfit=args.overfit,
        )

        return (
            DATA_MODULE,
            INV_SCALER,
            SCALER,
            NULL_VAL,
            PLOT_VAR_IDXS,
            PLOT_VAR_NAMES,
            PAD_VAL,
        )
    # Try to use my own data set here
    elif config.dset == "custom":
        data_dir = "./spacetimeformer/mydata"

        # Define data transformations
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((256, 256)),  # Resize the images to a specific size
            transforms.ToTensor(),          # Convert images to tensors
            transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),  # Normalize the pixel values
        ])
        
        # Create the custom image dataset
        dataset = CUSTOMDset(data_dir, context_points=config.context_points, transform=transform)
        
        DATA_MODULE = stf.data.DataModule(
            datasetCls=dataset,
            dataset_kwargs={"context_points": config.context_points},
            batch_size=config.batch_size,
            workers=config.workers,
            overfit=args.overfit,
        )

        # Rest of the values remain the same as in the "mnist" and "cifar" cases
        PLOT_VAR_IDXS = [0]
        PLOT_VAR_NAMES = ["Reds"]
        PAD_VAL = None
    
        return (
            DATA_MODULE,
            INV_SCALER,
            SCALER,
            NULL_VAL,
            PLOT_VAR_IDXS,
            PLOT_VAR_NAMES,
            PAD_VAL,
        )
```

I call `create_dset` later:

```
    (
        data_module,
        inv_scaler,
        scaler,
        null_val,
        plot_var_idxs,
        plot_var_names,
        pad_val,
    ) = create_dset(args)
```

and I use it in `test_dataloader = data_module.test_dataloader()`.
**
Here I got an error message: `data_module` object is not callable.**

I think the problem may be with the `CUSTOMDset` I defined in another file, so I also enclosed it here.

```
class CUSTOMDset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_dir, context_points, transform=None):
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.context_points = context_points
        self.transform = transform
        self.file_list = os.listdir(self.data_dir)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_list)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.data_dir, self.file_list[i])
        img = Image.open(img_name)
        y = img.convert("RGB")

        y_c = y.crop((0, 0, self.context_points, y.size[1]))
        y_t = y.crop((self.context_points, 0, y.size[0], y.size[1]))

        x = torch.arange(y.size[1]).view(-1, 1).float() / y.size[1]
        x_c = x[: self.context_points]
        x_t = x[self.context_points:]

        if self.transform:
            y_c = self.transform(y_c)
            y_t = self.transform(y_t)

        return x_c, y_c, x_t, y_t
```

I've tried to print `data_module`. The result is

```
<spacetimeformer.data.datamodule.DataModule object at 0x7f59cd8f84c0>
```

Error message (detailed):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_my.py", line 525, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "train_my.py", line 435, in main
    test_dataloader = data_module.test_dataloader()
  File "/home/spacetimeformer/spacetimeformer/data/datamodule.py", line 37, in test_dataloader
    return self._make_dloader("test", shuffle=shuffle)
  File "/home/spacetimeformer/spacetimeformer/data/datamodule.py", line 44, in _make_dloader
    self.datasetCls(**self.dataset_kwargs, split=split),
TypeError: 'CUSTOMDset' object is not callable
```

The environment: python=3.8, torch=2.0.1

**Any idea or suggestion will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.**

(adding some relevant code--23:46 2023/8/3)

```
def test_dataloader(self, shuffle=False):
    return self._make_dloader("test", shuffle=shuffle)

def _make_dloader(self, split, shuffle=False):
    if self.overfit:
        split = "train"
        shuffle = True
    return DataLoader(
        self.datasetCls(**self.dataset_kwargs, split=split),
        shuffle=shuffle,
        batch_size=self.batch_size,
        num_workers=self.workers,
        collate_fn=self.collate_fn,
    )
```

Comment: What is stf.data.DataModule() returning? Seems it is not a callable.

Comment: @Davy `DataModule.test_dataloader` will call `make_dloader`, and finally return a `DataLoader`. I've uploaded relevant code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

An object of the class "Dataloader" is returned. This object is not callable (it is not a function that can be called). This is the error you are seeing.

Comment: Did this solve your question pls?